# Error when showing snackbar on error using provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have the current situation when the user login, I call the method from the provider, and based on the status I render the new state. When there is an error, I want to show back the button with a snack bar containing the error message.

But I got the following error:

**Error**

```
The following assertion was thrown building Consumer<AuthProvider>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AuthProvider>]):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

**Provider**

```
void signIn(String email, String password) async {
    _logLoading(_loginStatus);
    try {
      print("Loggin with email $email and password $password");
      _user = await _authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      _logSuccess(_loginStatus, 'You have logged successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      _logError(_loginStatus, e.toString());
    }
}

  void _logLoading(StatusHolder statusHolder) {
    statusHolder.status = Status.Loading;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _logSuccess(StatusHolder statusHolder, String message) {
    statusHolder.status = Status.Success;
    statusHolder.successMessage = message;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _logError(StatusHolder statusHolder, String message) {
    statusHolder.status = Status.Failure;
    statusHolder.errorMessage = message;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**Widget**

```
Consumer<AuthProvider>(
  builder: (context, model, child) {
              switch (model.loginStatus.status) {
                case Status.Loading:
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                case Status.Failure:
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text(model.loginStatus.errorMessage),
                  ));
                  return _idlePart(context);
                case Status.Success:
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                      ));
                  return Container();

                case Status.Idle:
                default:
                  return _idlePart(context);
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: The error message indicates, that somewhere in your `build` method you trigger another invocation of `build`. Do you invocate `notifyListener` somwhere there? This could be the reason because `notifyListeners()` triggers a build.

Comment: The only place I call notifylisteners is in the sign-in function in the authprovider class

Comment: I cannot see that you call `notifiyListeners()` in your `signIn()`. Do you have more code to show?

Comment: I update the code with it, the logs functions call it

Comment: What's the content of `_idlePart(context)`?